# Laravel-Excel Maatwebsite create Dropdown to excel file OR get dropdown data from another sheet?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

Below is my code for create a excel with Dropdown script is working find but i am not able to get Dropdown data form another sheet.

```
        \Excel::create('file', function($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('variants', function($sheet2) {

            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A1", "Size");
            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A2", "S");
            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A3", "M");
            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A4", "L");
            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A5", "XL");
            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A6", "XXL");
            $sheet2->SetCellValue("A7", "XXXL");

        });

        $excel->sheet('product', function($sheet) {

            $sheet->_parent->addNamedRange(
                new \PHPExcel_NamedRange(
                'size', $sheet, 'A2:A7'
                )
            );

            $objValidation = $sheet->getCell('D1')->getDataValidation();
            $objValidation->setType(\PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
            $objValidation->setErrorStyle(\PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
            $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
            $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
            $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
            $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
            $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
            $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
            $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
            $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
            $objValidation->setFormula1('countries'); //note this!
        });

    })->download("xlsx");
```

The actually problem on below code

```
$sheet->_parent->addNamedRange(
     new \PHPExcel_NamedRange(
        'size', $sheet, 'A2:A7'
     )
);
```

On above script when i passed `$sheet` it's working find but now i want to read `A2:A7` from `$sheet2` how can i passed `$sheet2` instead of `$sheet`.

Thanks